# Mysql Joining with Case

Tags: mysql

I have two tables sales and sale_taxes

Table : sales

```
sale_id  | sale_cost | sale_discount | sale_tax  | sale_total 
-------------------------------------------------------------
131      |   30      |      10       |   3       |   23
```

Table : sale_taxes which stores the tax break up

```
sale_tax_id  | sale_id   | tax_id | tax_percent | tax_amount  
-------------------------------------------------
1211         |  131      | 1    |      10     |   2
1332         |  131      | 2    |      5      |   1
```

Where tax_id 1 is for VAT, and 2 is for Service Tax.

I want help for a query in fetching a result

```
sale_id  | sale_cost | sale_discount | sale_tax  | sale_total | VAT | Service Tax
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
131      |   30      |      10       |   3       |   23       | 2   |      1
```

Comment: How are the 2 tables related?  Does the `sales` table `sale_id` equal the `sale_taxes` table `sale_tax_id`?  Generally you need a field to `join` the 2 tables together.

Comment: sorry missed it. Thanks for the asking.

Comment: Please how are your tables related?

Comment: Apologies. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, there are a couple options to do this.  One is to `join` the table to itself multiple times:

```
select s.sale_id, s.sale_cost, s.sale_discount, s.sale_tax, s.sale_total,
      st1.tax_amount as vat,
      st2.tax_amount as service_tax
from sales s
    left join sales_taxes st1 on s.sale_id = st1.sale_id and st1.tax_id = 1
    left join sales_taxes st2 on s.sale_id = st2.sale_id and st2.tax_id = 2
```

If the data may or may not exist, use the `outer join`.  If you know both records will exist, you can use an `inner join` instead.

---

Here's an alternative method using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select s.sale_id, s.sale_cost, s.sale_discount, s.sale_tax, s.sale_total,
      max(case when st.tax_id = 1 then st.tax_amount end) as vat,
      max(case when st.tax_id = 2 then st.tax_amount end) as service_tax
from sales s
    left join sales_taxes st on s.sale_id = st.sale_id
group by s.sale_id
```

But I believe the first method would be more efficient.